# How does the 'yield' keyword in python really work, especially when it comes with recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, generator, yield, iterable

I'm using python to flatten a nested list, like `[1,2,[3,4,[5,[[6,7]]]]]`, I want to create an generator so I can use for loop to print all the numbers one by one in the nested list. But it just does not work as I expected.

When I replace the 'yield' keyword with 'print', the numbers get printed one by one. However in that way it is no longer a generator.

The following does not work properly:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def flatten(nested):
    for item in nested:
        if isinstance(item, Iterable):
            flatten(item)
        else:
            yield item
x = [1,2,[3,4,[5,[[6,7]]]]]
y = flatten(x)

for element in y:
    print(element)
```

However, if I wrote the code like below, where I replaced the `yield` with
`print`, the numbers will get printed properly

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def flatten(nested):
    for item in nested:
        if isinstance(item, Iterable):
            flatten(item)
        else:
            print(item)
x = [1,2,[3,4,[5,[[6,7]]]]]
y = flatten(x)
```

With the 'yield', if I wrote:

```
x = [[1,2],[3,4,[5,[[6,7]]]]]
y = flatten(x)
y.__next__()
```

The error message will be `y.__next__() StopIteration`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're never returning or yielding from the recursive calls. add a [yield from](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380-syntax-for-delegating-to-a-subgenerator) and it should work.

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def flatten(nested):
    for item in nested:
        if isinstance(item, Iterable):
            yield from flatten(item) #change here.
        else:
            yield item
x = [1,2,[3,4,[5,[[6,7]]]]]
y = flatten(x)

for element in y:
    print(element)
#Output:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Note that this problem was also inherently present in your original function, whether you would have used a yield or a return.  This is why you should be careful when using `print` only and no returns in recursive calls, it can mask the fact that while the code runs properly, the outputs are not correctly captured/used.

Answer (score 1):

This fixes your code:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable


def flatten(nested):
    for item in nested:
        if isinstance(item, Iterable):
            yield from flatten(item)
        else:
            yield item


x = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, [[6, 7]]]]]
y = flatten(x)

for element in y:
    print(element)
```

This works because you call `flatten` again, but forget to `yield from` (after all, the new call also returns a generator)

Note that `isinstance(item, Iterable)` is probably not what you want, since it will break for strings. Strings are `Iterable`, but in a `for` loop, the characters that are returned from it are strings themselves. Probably better to check if it is a list.

```
def flatten(nested):
    for item in nested:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            yield from flatten(item)
        else:
            yield item


for element in flatten([1, 2, ['three', 4, [5, [[6, 7]]]]]):
    print(element)
```

Comment: You just reminded me a tricky point in python : characters are stings! So if I include a string in my list, it will flatten it into characters, however characters are still stings so it keeps flattening.....That's a disaster. Thanks for noting me of that!